# RequireJS throws error when trying to load paths while running on Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, cdn

I am trying to runt the following code on using node:

```
const require = require("requirejs");

require.config({
    paths: {
        d3: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.16.0/d3.min',
        plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min',
        jquery: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min'
    },

    shim: {
        plotly: {
            deps: ['d3', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'plotly'
        }
    }
});


require(['plotly'], function(Plotly) {
    window.Plotly = Plotly;
})
```

Inspiration for this comes from here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436184/using-requirejs-to-load-plotly-and-d3)

Now when I run:

```
node main.js
```

I get the following error:

```
throw err;

Error: Tried loading "plotly" at https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js then tried node's require("plotly") and it failed with error: Error: Cannot find module 'plotly'
```

Could someone please kindly explain what is going on and how I can fix this error message?

Comment: https://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#2: *"RequireJS in Node can only load modules that are on the local disk -- fetching modules across http, for instance, is not supported at this time."*

Comment: Although I'm not sure what you're trying to do and why? Node doesn't have a window object so even if you manage to load the libraries then `window.Plotly` would just fail. Also unclear why you're using RequireJS and what you're planning to do with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @GuyIncognito, I was meant to take out the window.plotly thing. Essentially I will be running this stuff inside a jsdom instance. I was trying to load these external libraries for unit testing purposes. I think your first comment clears this issue up for me thanks!